# Allow multiple instances of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

> Disclaimer: This may be a better question on SuperUser, but my use
>   case matches SO.

I'm trying to develop an Angular app on my local computer; I'm not yet ready to set up a webserver or anything like that. I'm loading some JSON configuration files from the same directory, and I'm running into Origin Policy issues (which was expected).

I know that programs like gChat can run multiple instances with the `/mutex` flag (I think that's it, it's been a while since I tried that). Is there any such provision for Google Chrome? Basically, I'd like to run Chrome as my main browser for everything I do, and then open a separate instance with lowered web security for testing purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring up a development web server, serving data from the current working directory, using:

```
python -mSimpleHTTPServer
```

This doesn't directly answer your question, I know. But hopefully it's even better than a direct answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, I've got multiple ways of serving this data locally - Node, Python, Mongoose - but I was hoping to find a way not to have to spool something up for what is, essentially, a client-side app. Much easier just to double-click my index.html file in my Explorer window and pull up a browser....

Comment: For what it's worth, I also use multiple profiles on my Windows installation, so not having to set up server environments for each one would be beneficial.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, detailed in my answer, but I upvoted your answer (as it was good and provided alternative solutions).

Comment: Edit: My solution is stupid. If you can, use a local web server. It can still be a bit painful in Windows, but it's better than the alternatives (and if you have Node and a real command line, you're completely set).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this - although Chrome won't let you run multiple instances, you can run Chrome and Chrome Canary side-by-side simultaneously. So now, Chrome is my main browser, and Chrome Canary (with the `--disable-web-security`) flag is my testing environment. So far, I haven't had any issues with discrepancies between the browsers.